# Как вставить символы до и перед выделенным текстом в memo?

Tags: delphi

Как вставить символы до и перед выделенным текстом в memo?

Comment: У ТМемо есть свойства: SelStart - позиция первого выделенного элемента и SelLength - длинная выделенного текста. С помощью этих свойств и методов Copy(), Pos() - вы сможете решить свою задачу

Comment: Да, я знаю об этих свойствах, но не приложу ума, как это должно выглядеть, поэтому и задал вопрос.

Comment: Какая делфи?

Comment: У меня Delphi 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  A_ = '_BeginText_';
  B_ = '_EndText_';
var
  tmp: String;
  x, y: integer;
begin
  tmp := Memo1.Text;
  x := Memo1.SelStart;
  y := Memo1.SelLength;
  insert(A_, tmp, x + 1);
  insert(B_, tmp, x + Length(A_) + y + 1);
  Memo1.Text := tmp;
  // FileList('D:\Мусорка\dlatz\chahua3462', Memo1.Lines);
end;
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо, вы мне очень помогли!